# Global Dimension 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, global-dimension

I have a question about rings of global dimension one.

I read that these rings are hereditary rings, that is, every right ideal is projective.

How can I prove this fact ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you ever seen this short exact sequence: $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$?

Comment: @user26857 that implies that $I$ is projective, but how can I prove that if a ring is hereditary then it has global dimension 1?

Comment: Maybe using that the global dimension is the supremum of $\mathrm{pd}_R(R/I)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm starting with all these concepts on dimension.

Answer (score 1):

A ring $R$ is (left) hereditary if and only if all (left) modules have projective resolutions of length at most $1$. But this is by definition equivalent to saying that the (left) global dimension is at most $1$.

Comment: How can I prve that "A ring R is (left) hereditary if and only if all (left) modules have projective resolutions of length at most" ??

Comment: Your definition of hereditary is that every (left) ideal is projective. A (left ) ideal is a submodule, so it follows.

Comment: I can't see why if every left ideal is projective, then all left modules have projective resolutions of length at most 1...